# java.lang.NullPointerException retrieving ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, null

I have a function to return an arraylist;

```
public ArrayList sendUpdatedList()
{
    return connections;
}
```

this is how im calling it, from a different class;

```
connections = client.sendUpdatedList();
```

Its producing a nullpointererror. "connections" is set further up in the class and initialized. help!

Comment: If this code is generating a NPE, then `client` is `null`. (BTW, Why is `connections` being set "further up in the class and initialized" and also being set in the line you posted?)

Comment: post the full stacktrace of the NPE, to see where its coming from

Comment: Guys, im incredibly sorry, i forgot to call my function to get client in the first place... how stupid - thanks for responding though!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the only actual access to a reference here is `client`, then in here the problem is `client` is `null`.

Your [stacktrace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/572670) could actually have shown you that the method you thought is responsible, is not actually called.

As a side note, you should avoid using [raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) (`ArrayList`), and try to stick with [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) (`ArrayList<SomeClass>`).